# Python: ElementTree, get the namespace string of an Element

Tags: python, elementtree

This XML file is named `example.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>14.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>.com.foobar.flubber</groupId>
  <artifactId>uberportalconf</artifactId>
  <version>13-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Environment for UberPortalConf</name>
  <description>This is the description</description>    
  <properties>
      <birduberportal.version>11</birduberportal.version>
      <promotiondevice.version>9</promotiondevice.version>
      <foobarportal.version>6</foobarportal.version>
      <eventuberdevice.version>2</eventuberdevice.version>
  </properties>
  <!-- A lot more here, but as it is irrelevant for the problem I have removed it -->
</project>
```

If I load example.xml and parse it with ElementTree I can see its namespace is `http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0`.

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> tree = ElementTree.parse('example.xml')
>>> print tree.getroot()
<Element '{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}project' at 0x26ee0f0>
```

I have not found a method to call to get just the namespace from an `Element` without resorting to parsing the `str(an_element)` of an Element. It seems like there got to be a better way.

Comment: do you know how to use the find method in this cases? it didnt work here...

Answer (score 33):

This is a perfect task for a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

```
import re

def namespace(element):
    m = re.match(r'\{.*\}', element.tag)
    return m.group(0) if m else ''
```

Comment: After fighting for a while with this issue, this is the best solution I found. I can't believe that the API don't get you a way to ask for the namespace and, at the same time, it doesn't return the attribute 'xmlns' when doing 'rootElement.keys()'. Sure there is a good reason for that but I can't find it at this moment.

Comment: add `r` before regular exp please make this answer perfect.

Comment: @Jiu thank you so much. I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: to get namespace without curly braces included:
re.match(r'\{(.*)\}', element.tag).group(1)

Comment: After adding `r` before the regex the  ``\``s  are redundant.

Comment: @FNia no they're not. You need a way to tell the regex engine that you're looking for the literal character and it shouldn't try to interpret it.

Comment: @MarkRansom Removing the ``\``s certainly works (tried), but I apologize it has nothing to do with the `r`.  It just works with curly braces in this case because they can't be interpreted any other way. Other special characters would need to be escaped.

Answer (score 30):

The namespace should be in [`Element.tag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tag) right before the "actual" tag:

```
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> root.tag
'{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}project'
```

To know more about namespaces, take a look at [ElementTree: Working with Namespaces and Qualified Names](https://web.archive.org/web/20200721203629/http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm).

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure if this is possible with `xml.etree`, but here is how you could do it with `lxml.etree`:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('example.xml')
>>> tree.xpath('namespace-uri(.)')
'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0'
```

Comment: I get `unresolved import: etree` using Python 2.7.2 in Windows. `xpath` wasn´t available as a method when using `xml.etree` and if I use `find()` (which supports xpath expressions) the `'namespace-uri(.)'` statement still doesn´t work.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, [see pr on gh](https://github.com/samatjain/gpxsplitter/pull/3)

Comment: This has been the best solution that I've seen. I normally use xmlstarlet but I may switch now.

Comment: Why isn't this marked as answer? this is precisely what is asked for here! ... Except the part it is lxml and not xml...

Comment: for `lxml` a simpler way to get the namespace is `tree.getroot().nsmap`

Comment: @ccpizza With [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067800/xmlns-namespace-breaking-lxml) I have to use `tree.getroot().nsmap[None]`. Is the example misformatted ?

Comment: @Jona: I'd assume that using `None` is a way to address the default namespace, ie the one which is declared without a prefix.

Answer (score 11):

Without using regular expressions:

```
>>> root
<Element '{http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84}urlset' at 0x2f7cc10>

>>> root.tag.split('}')[0].strip('{')
'http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84'
```

Comment: a similar answer `root.tag[1:root.tag.index('}')]`

Comment: This answer was the most simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `lxml.xtree` library's element has a dictionary called `nsmap`,  which shows all the namespace that are in use in the current tag scope.

```
>>> item = tree.getroot().iter().next()
>>> item.nsmap
{'md': 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata'}
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is:

```
ElementTree._namspace_map[ElementTree._namspace_map.values().index('')]
```

but only if you have been calling

```
ElementTree.register_namespace(prefix,uri)
```

in response to every *event=="start-ns"* received while iterating through the result of

```
ET.iterparse(...)
```

and you registered for *"start-ns"*

The answer the question "what is the default namespace?", it is necessary to clarify two points:

(1) XML specifications say that the default namespace is not necessarily global throughout the tree, rather the default namespace can be re-declared at any element under root, and inherits downwards until meeting another default namespace re-declaration.

(2) The ElementTree module can (de facto) handle XML-like documents which have no root default namespace, -if- they have no namespace use anywhere in the document.  (* there may be less strict conditions, e.g., that is "if" and not necessarily "iff").

It's probably also worth considering "what do you want it for?"  Consider that XML files can be semantically equivalent, but syntactically very different.  E.g., the following three files are semantically equivalent, but A.xml has one default namespace declaration, B.xml has three, and C.xml has none.

```
A.xml:
<a xlmns="http://A" xlmns:nsB0="http://B0" xlmns:nsB1="http://B1">
     <nsB0:b/>
     <nsB1:b/>
</a>

B.xml:
<a xlmns="http://A">
     <b xlmns="http://B0"/>
     <b xlmns="http://B1"/>
</a>

C.xml:
<{http://A}a>
     <{http://B0}b/>
     <{http://B1}b/>
</a>
```

The file C.xml is the canonical expanded syntactical representation presented to the ElementTree search functions.

If you are certain a priori that there will be no namespace collisions, you can modify the element tags while parsing as discussed here: [Python ElementTree module: How to ignore the namespace of XML files to locate matching element when using the method "find", "findall"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412496/python-elementtree-module-how-to-ignore-the-namespace-of-xml-files-to-locate-ma)

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be easier to take a look at the attributes:

```
>>> root.attrib
{'{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}schemaLocation':
   'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd'}
```

Comment: Certainly easier than parsing `str(the_element)`. But I guess parsing `the_element.tag` is even a bit easier. As I am only interested in the namespace. What do you think?

Comment: I think that @RikPoggi's answer seems the best one (actually, I upvoted it). In fact, getting the namespace should be as easy as `re.search('\{(.*)\}', the_element.tag).group(1)`. With my answer it looks you could use `the_element.attrib.values()[0].split()[0]`, but, indeed, it doesn't look so much straightforward and it isn't guaranteed that you won't get any other attributes in the future.

Answer (score -1):

combining some of the answers above, I think the shortest code is

```
theroot = tree.getroot()
theroot.attrib[theroot.keys()[0]]
```

Comment: This is not accurate, because the xmlns might not be the first attribute of the root. In fact, I'm currently trying to parse a TCX file and the xmlns isn't showing up as an attribute of the root at all.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution on ElementTree 3.9+,

```
def get_element_namespaces(filename, element):
    namespace = []
    for key, value in ET.iterparse(filename, events=['start', 'start-ns']):
        print(key, value)
        if key == 'start-ns':
            namespace.append(value)
        else:
            if ET.tostring(element) == ET.tostring(value):
                return namespace
            namespace = []
    return namespaces
```

This would return an array of [prefix:URL] tuples like this:

```
[('android', 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'), ('tools', 'http://schemas.android.com/tools')]
```

Comment: This can't run because you have typos and no context in there.