# python lxml - how to get the value of a subelement in XML

Tags: python, xml, lxml

The XML:

```
<tree>
  <row>
     <a>This is a</a>
     <b>This is b</b>
  </row>
</tree>
```

So I have seen many solutions across the web and looked up many of them already. The following didn't work for me:

```
tree = etree.XML('file.xml')
print tree[0].findtext('a'). // None
print tree[0].find('a'). // None
print tree[0].xpath('a') // None
print tree[0].xpath('/a') //None
print tree[0].xpath('//a') //None
print tree[0].xpath('/a') //None
print tree.xpath('//row/a') //None
print tree.xpath('//row/a/text()') //None
```

The only way i found is like doing `tree[0][0].text` 
But my actual XML contains 25 subelements and it isn't really clean code to do this 25 times..

Maybe you guys know what i am doing wrong?

I also know there is something like BeautifulSoup but after testing, i came to the conclusion this does not fit my case due to the performance.. ([benchmark here](https://www.crummy.com/2012/01/22/0))

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally figured out my problem. It was the name spacing of the xml.
I didn't do anything with it, so i though it was not necessary to look at.

The XML was slightly different:

```
<tree xmlns="http://www.schemas.net/schema/MyXMLSchema">
  <row>
     <a>This is a</a>
     <b>This is b</b>
  </row>
</tree>
```

So what i needed to do in the find was add the namespace.
To do this dynamically i used the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9513828/6434747) from an other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513540/python-elementtree-get-the-namespace-string-of-an-element) 
Like this:

```
tree = etree.XML('file.xml')
namespace = tree.xpath('namespace-uri(.)')
for row in tree:
    print row.findtext('{%s}a' % namespace)
    print row.findtext('{%s}b' % namespace)

# This is a
# This is b
```

if concerned about not only containing rows, `tree.iter('row')` is indeed, like [DeepSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453822/deepspace) pointed out, a better outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.iter` and a `for` loop.

```
for row_node in tree.iter('row'):
    a_node = row_node.find('a')
    b_node = row_node.find('b')
    print(a_node.text)
    print(b_node.text)

# This is a
# This is b
```